# Writing CSV into Multiple Lines

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV that I'm trying to get in the following format:

```
Blocklist, Name
BL1, Name1
BL2, Name2
BL3, Name3
```

However, I'm getting my blocklists printed in 1 long row under the headers.

```
Blocklist, Name
BL1, BL2, BL3, BL4
```

How am I able to split this into multiple rows as described above? Here is my code so far

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
if response.status_code != 200:
    raise ApiError(response.status_code)
    print('Something went wrong')

with open('new_file.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    json_data = response.json()

    vt_result = []
    for k, v in json_data['scans'].items():
        if not v.get("detected", False):
            vt_result.append(k)
    csv_writer.writerow(vt_result)
```

I've tried using

```
    for k, v in json_data['scans'].items():
        if not v.get("detected", False):
            #vt_result.append(k)
            csv_writer.writerow(k)
```

But that prints commas between everything character. For example, `N,a,m,e,1`

Comment: What does the input JSON look like?  Make a [mcve] giving input JSON, code attempt, and output desired.  Remove unnecessary code.  Make a runnable example.

Comment: And `.writerow()`  expects a list.  To write `BL1,Name1` use `.writerow(['BL1','Name1'])`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `csv` is expecting a dict. Changing to the following resolved my issue.

```
    for k, v in json_data['scans'].items():
        if not v.get("detected", False):
            #vt_result.append(k)
            csv_writer.writerow([k])
```